# CSS diamond shape, in the middle of the nav bar

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

My code display correctly on local, with a diamond shape in the middle of the navigation bar, but the "plus" sign missing the bottom part.(It's what I want to know how to fix it)

However, the outlook changed significantly after I pasted code into JSfiddle and Codepen.io

http://codepen.io/yumikohey/pen/PwPYxN
http://jsfiddle.net/yumiko/ae1zmqpa/

CSS

```
body{

}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}

#top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #C2973C;
}

#socialBar_top{
    width: 25%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    float: right;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#expandButton {

    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 46%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.centerBox{
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-top: -10px;
}

#diamondButton {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #C2973C;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
}

#diamondButton:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 30px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #C2973C;
}

#plusSign {
    margin: -30px 0 -0 -14px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your generous help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
#plusSign {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 2em;
   margin: 0 0 0 -9px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 29px;
   z-index: 100000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, what does the absolute do here? I make it look better with this code,

#plusSign {
 margin-left: -14px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 3em;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 100;
}

Comment: But the issue is I don't know how it will look when it goes to responsive site though..

Comment: Absolute align the plus sign in relative with diamond shape.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue with this code,

```
#plusSign {
    margin-left: -14px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

But can anyone explain why codePen and JSfiddle cannot display my code correctly?